# Iterating nested sublists dynamically

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dynamic, arcpy

I am trying to create a runlist that can be used to process data in chunks as a separate function has to be run once the first batch's processing is complete. I have that section down. What I am having problems with is creating the runlist.
I have a list of processing areas and if one of the areas overlaps with one that has already been tested, then it needs to be moved to the next sublist. Then that sublist will be tested in the same way. The iteration will stop when the last sublist is a length of 1.

### Example

1. Initial List: `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` (3 & 4 overlap with two; 5 & 6 overlaps with 3 & 4)
2. Test #1 output: `[[1,2],[3,4,5,6]]`
3. Test #2 output: `[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]`

### Current Code

```
def containTest(a, b):
    return not set(a).isdisjoint(b)

def getValueList(inputTable, field):
    valueSet = set()  # set to hold unique values
    # use data access search cursor combined with, 'with'
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(inputTable, field) as values:
        # iterate through all values returned by Search Cursor
        for value in values:
            # Add value to set. If the value is not present,
            # it will be added. If it is present, the set will not
            # allow duplicates.
            valueSet.add(value[0])
    # sort and return list of values
    return sorted(valueSet)


import sys
import os
import traceback

# ArcGIS initialization
from arcpy.sa import *  # for ArcPy map algebra
import arcpy
arcpy.SetProduct("ArcInfo")
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")  # spatial analyst license

# Geoprocessing error exception
from arcpy import ExecuteError as GPError

# ENV setup
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

try:  
    # <get arguments from the command line here>
    vpupth = r'C:\TmpSS\NHDPlus06'
    workp = vpupth + os.sep + "RemoveSinks"  # (type Workspace) Path where results written into folders for each sink
    sinktbl = r"C:\TmpSS\NHDPlus06\RemoveSinks\sinks_00.shp"  # list of areas to process, integers are in the "GridCode" field

    # vrbls to identify first times through loops
    firsttime = True

    # Copy sinktbl to in_memory
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(sinktbl, "in_memory\sinktbl")
    sinktbl = "in_memory\sinktbl"

    # Make Layers of needed feature classes
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(vsink, "in_memory\lyrSink")
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(vcatch, "in_memory\lyrCatch")

    runlist = [[], []]
    chkdupes = set()

    sinknum = 1
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(sinktbl, ("GridCode")) as sinkrows:
        for sinkrow in sinkrows:
            sinkid = sinkrow[0]

            print "Processing Sink " + str(sinknum) + " GridCode = " + str(sinkid)

            # Select the sink specified in the table row
            arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("in_memory\lyrSink", "NEW_SELECTION", "GridCode = %s" % sinkid)
            # Write out to shapefile sinkprj
            arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("in_memory\lyrSink", "in_memory\sinkprj")
            # Select the catchment the sink falls within
            arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("in_memory\lyrCatch", "INTERSECT", "in_memory\lyrSink", "", "NEW_SELECTION")
            # Select the catchments surrounding the catchment containing sink
            arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("in_memory\lyrCatch", "BOUNDARY_TOUCHES", "in_memory\lyrCatch", "", "NEW_SELECTION")
            # Write inner catchments out to shapefile catchi
            arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("in_memory\lyrCatch", "in_memory\catchi")

            # Select another tier of catchments surrounding the selected catchments (second tier out from sink)
            arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("in_memory\lyrCatch", "BOUNDARY_TOUCHES", "in_memory\lyrCatch", "", "NEW_SELECTION")
            # Write outer catchments out to shapefile catcho
            arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("in_memory\lyrCatch", "in_memory\catcho")    
            catchlist = set(getValueList("in_memory\catcho", "GridCode"))

            i = 0
            if firsttime is True:
                chkdupes |= catchlist
                firsttime = False
                runlist[i].append(sinkid)
                print "First time copy complete"
                i += 1
            else:
                if containTest(chkdupes, catchlist):
                    print "catchlist exists, moving sink to next iteration"
                    runlist[i + 1].append(sinkid)
                else:
                    print "sink does not exist in catchment list"
                    chkdupes |= catchlist
                    print "added to round one"
                    runlist[i].append(sinkid)
                i += 1

            del catchlist
            arcpy.Delete_management("in_memory\catcho")
            arcpy.Delete_management("in_memory\catchi")
            sinknum += 1

        print runlist

except arcpy.ExecuteError:
    # Get the tool error messages
    msgs = arcpy.GetMessages(2)
    # Return tool error messages for use with a script tool
    arcpy.AddError(msgs)
    # Print tool error messages for use in Python/PythonWin
    print msgs

except:
    # Get the traceback object
    tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
    tbinfo = traceback.format_tb(tb)[0]
    # Concatenate information together concerning the error into a message string
    pymsg = "PYTHON ERRORS:\nTraceback info:\n" + tbinfo + "\nError Info:\n" + str(sys.exc_info()[1])
    msgs = "ArcPy ERRORS:\n" + arcpy.GetMessages(2) + "\n"

    # Return python error messages for use in script tool or Python Window
    arcpy.AddError(pymsg)
    arcpy.AddError(msgs)

    # Print Python error messages for use in Python / Python Window
    print pymsg + "\n"
    print msgs
finally:
  # Clean up here (delete cursors, temp files)
  pass
```

Thanks to all that take a look, the help is very appreciated. I feel like there is an advanced method of performing this task but my lack of knowledge is preventing me from seeing the solution.

Comment: I think doing a few things will help you get good answers on this and future questions: 1) Define the problem more clearly. For example, what is a "processing area"? How do you define "overlap" (I didn't see obvious overlap in your example) 2) Define simple input and the output you hope to get. What are the logical steps between the input you showed and the outputs? 3) Minimize the code you share so that everyone only sees the code directly related to your question. Lots of unrelated code will discourage people from trying.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit difficult to understand but since I had the same problem I actually know what you want. You want to order a number of elements into boxes where elements in higher numbered boxes only depend on elements in lower numbered boxes and there are as few boxes as possible. Your application are is GIS, most probably drawing of overlapping image areas.

The solution is not very difficult. My input data structure is a list of entries. Each entry has an element id and a list of dependencies of this element (ids of the elements this element depends on). The output is a list of sets of element ids where each set depicts a box of elements which can be processed/drawn at the same time.

The solution is iterative: reduce the list of available elements by all elements that have no dependencies anymore and put all these elements into a new box. Then reduce the dependencies of the remaining elements by removing all dependencies to elements that just have been put into a box. The `difference` function of a set in Python as well as list comprehensions come in very handy.

The code example is:

```
def order_by_dependency(input):
    # start with empty output
    output = []

    # in a loop
    while input:

        # find entries without dependencies and add to output
        output.append([i for (i, j) in input if len(j) == 0])

        # reduce input by deleting all elements without dependencies and removing dependencies
        former_dependencies = set(output[-1])
        input = [(i, j - former_dependencies) for (i, j) in input if len(j) > 0]

    return output

input = [[1, []], [2, []], [3, set([2])], [4, set([2])], [5, set([3, 4])], [6, set([3, 4])]]
print(order_by_dependency(input))
```

and the output is as expected:

> [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]